# facing some issues with bootstrap and jquery navigation bar not being responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap navigation bar. On phones (and other lower resolution devices), this is not collapsing the menu to be a dropdown.
Here is my code:

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid" id="navfluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./Index.html">Stadtfestlauf</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="active"><a href="./Index.html">Startseite</a></li>
               <li><a href="./Rueckblick.html">R&uuml;ckblick</a></li>
               <li><a href="./Wettbewerb.html">Wettbewerb</a></li>    
               <li><a href="./anmelden.html">Anmelden</a></li>
               <li><a href="./sponsoren.html">Sponsoren</a></li>
           </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I got this example from stackoverflow. I am importing bootstrap js after importing jquery (v2.1.4).

Comment: Can you specify what does not change?

Comment: On small width (phones) is still belt but i need button with "dropdown" menu.